# JQM+MVC4+Date Input + Android = Crash browser

Tags: android, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

Testing a jquery mobile app on android (galaxy s2)

JQM 1.2.0, JQ 1.8.2

In my mvc4 project, I have a model that defines a nullable Date field.

The model annotates the data type as "Date" (not DateTime etc)

I also have the field annotated as Required.

When I test this using a desktop browser, the date input fields shows a dropdown calendar selector which let's me select a date.

On my Android device, I don't see this dropdown. But if I click the field directly, sometimes it will pop up a build-in date picker. Other times it will do weird things- the screen may try to zoom just a bit (5% or so), try clicking the input a couple more times and things finally lock up and the browser exits.

I've also noticed that using the "next" button while using the popup keyboard, to navigate to the next field, will navigate to this field and treat it as a normal text input. But after entering a date as text, and continue to navigate away, the text is eventually lost... and usually results in another lockup and crash out of browser.

Frustrating... any ideas?

Comment: I've had a bunch of issues getting JQM's date functionality to work with MVC4. Make sure "type='date'". The 'd' <i>has</i> to be lower case. I don't see the datepicker functionality at all on my Android device if it is upper cased. Are you seeing issues when you try to set a default date, too?